# Can we connect Hasura cloud to amazon redshift database? If yes how?

Tags: graphql, hasura

On official site they have mentioned the support for only those databases-->

https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/index.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That's an interesting question: a) on one side Redshift evolved from PostgreSQL 8.0.2, b) on other side - they changed a lot. Does it still a "postgresql flavour" - IDK. Searching [discussions](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/discussions?discussions_q=Redshift) returns 0 results. Maybe it's better to ask there

Comment: I see that it's still possible to connect to  Redshift with old `psql` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html . Would I have a Redshift DB at my disposal - I would try to connect as usual postgresql and then see does it works or not.